# Zooming effect with prosper class

Tags: templates, zooming

I use prosper class and I want to use zoom effect like in this page: 
[Zooming images out to specific locations in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79293/zooming-images-out-to-specific-locations-in-beamer)

the code dosn't work with me on prosper class, I need some help.
thanks :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your set-up.