# How to zooming out multiple figures in a single slide?

Tags: animations, tikz-pic, zooming

I'm preparing for a presentation. I have four figures (fig 1, fig 2, fig 3 and fig 4). I want to show the fig 1 in the whole slide and then zooming it out to the top left corner of the slide. Then to show the fig 2 in the whole slide and zooming it out to the top right corner of the slide. Similarly, fig 3 to the left bottom corner and fig 4 to the right bottom corner of the slide after showing them in the whole slide.

I do not have any idea on this. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the `\framezoom` command in `beamer` or the `spy` library from Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I got my answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79293/zooming-images-out-to-specific-locations-in-beamer?rq=1